# How do I map the indices of matching characters from two different strings using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, bioinformatics

Given two strings, A and B, of varying length each (they may have same length), I want to map the indices of B to the indices of A when character in A matches character in B.

```
# Example 1
string A: 'DSGIAKKBCLIDFCFCE'
string B: 'ABDCEF'
answer:   {0:4, 1:7, 2:11, 3:13, 4:16}

# Example 2
string A: 'ECDABF'
string B: 'ABDCEF'
answer:   {0:3, 1:4, 5:5}

# Example 3
string A: 'GKVRVNAL'
string B: 'TFTGKVRNHNLGDSVNALT'
answer: {3:0, 4:1, 5:2, 6:3, 14:4, 15:5, 16:6, 17:7}
```

The way I picture the code working is like this:

```
# For example 1
string A: DSGIAKKBCLIDFCFCE
B match:      A  B   D C  E
B index:      0  1   2 3  4
```

F is not there because it's not found after E in string A.

```
# For example 2
string A: ECDABF
B match:     ABF
B index:     1,2,5

# For example 3
string A: GKVRVNAL
B match:  GKVRVNAL
B index:  3,4,5,6,14,15,16,17
```

Comment: How would you deal with duplicates? In your example, you map `D` from `string A` (idx 3) to `D` in `string B` at idx 13, but there is also a `D` at idx 0.

Comment: @DanielLenz I'm starting the idx from 0. The first character from `string A` must match before the next character can be matched. In this example, the `D` at idx 0 is ignored. In the case for `C` at idx 3 in `string A`, it can either be idx 13 or idx 15 in `string B`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do not completely understand your question. Also, it should not be tagged with biopython as that library is not being used at all.

My attempt to your task would be

```
a = 'ABDCE'
b = 'DSGIAKKBCLIDFCFCE'

i = 0
result = []
for c_a in a:
    while i < len(b):
        if b[i] == c_a:
        result.append(i)
        break
    i += 1

print(result)
```

Which gives `[4, 7, 11, 13, 16]` for your example. I decided to use a list instead of a dict as the indices are consecutive numbers starting from 0 anyhow.

Comment: What about the question was unclear? I'm trying to get better at asking questions on here so I'd appreciate some feedback. I used a dict in the example because I wanted a lookup table for the mappings of the indices - I could make that clearer in the question.

Comment: But you get the same effect with a list. The indices are 0, 1, ... n. You can access the list with the appropriate index. result[2] gives you 11. There is no need to store the indices explicitly in a dict when you know they are going to be consecutive numbers starting from 0.

Comment: About the part with the question being unclear: I would suggest to provide more examples. Having 3 examples instead of only 1 makes it easier to test an algorithm and to understand what the expected outcome is - sometimes better than words could ever do :)

Comment: I added two more examples and tried to make it clear as to what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your feedback!